# Line fit in MATLAB or similar program

Tags: excel, matlab, curve-fitting

I have this data set:

```
10  12.14
20  36.82
30  59.48
40  79.96
50  89.45
60  95.04
70  95.50
80  95.50
90  95.50
100 95.50
110 95.50
```

The left column is time in minutes and the right is an arbitrary unit. I am trying to fit this data with an exponential of the form c(t)=C(1+e^(-t/T)). I have attempted to do this in excel and I believe it is beyond the limits of excel. I would like to do this in MATLAB however I am unaware of the commands to do so. Could someone tell me how to find the time constant T and the other constant C via MATLAB?

Comment: Have you considered taking the log of both sides so that you can just do a linear fit of appropriately defined variables?

Comment: Well, for one I am concerned that the fit will be poor considering the lack of data points and the second part of this statement is more of a question, the slope would be the time constant T correct?

Answer (score 0):

The logest function in Excel will do what you want.  Details with an example at [Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOGEST-function-f27462d8-3657-4030-866b-a272c1d18b4b)

Comment: So my equivalent Tau should be 37.114?